# http response is using chunked encoding when data is present

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, networking

I have a web service that, when called, may or may not send a body back with the response. For some reason, whenever there is no data the Content-Length header is present, but when I send back a body, a Transfer-Encoding: Chunked header is present instead of the Content-Length header. The request being sent up is, in fact, chunked, but i don't necessarily need the response to be as we want the payload to be a small as possible.

As the following code illustrates, I have tried forcing the content length when data is sent back, but even so, the response still does not have a Content-Length header. I have read that the existence of a Transfer-Encoding: Chunked header will override any COntent-Length header, but I can't figure out how to remove the Transfer-Encoding header, or even why it is there in the first place.

Here is the my callback for a new request:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setStatus(200);

    String mac = req.getHeader("x-kcid");
    String cmd = getCache(mac);

    if (cmd != null) {
        writeToStream(resp, cmd, "text/plain");
        clearCache(mac);
    }
}
```

and here is the method that actually writes the response:

```
private static void writeToStream(HttpServletResponse resp, String msg, String contentType) throws IOException {        
    resp.setContentType(contentType);
    resp.setContentLength(msg.getBytes().length);
    resp.getWriter().write(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE [doesn't allow](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Responses) setting the `Transfer-Encoding` or `Content-Length` header.
(That headers, and some others are **ignored and removed** from the response).